# How Define Callback Func Inside Of Calling Method?

Tags: c#, winapi, delegates, lambda, callback

I would like to declare / define my delegate and callback function inside of the calling method. Is that possible ? If yes how ? This is my code that I want to execute *my first implant operation* on:

```
delegate bool myDelegate(IntPtr module, string type, IntPtr lParam);

public static bool EnumResTypeProc(IntPtr module, string typename, IntPtr lParam)
{
    (((GCHandle) lParam).Target as List<string>).Add(typename);
    return true;
}

public static string[] getResourceTypes(IntPtr module)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    GCHandle pin = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
    WinApi.EnumResourceTypes(module, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new myDelegate(EnumResTypeProc)), (IntPtr)pin);
    pin.Free();
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

---

The closest I get:

```
delegate bool myDelegate(IntPtr module, string type, IntPtr lParam);

public static string[] getResourceTypes(IntPtr module)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    GCHandle pin = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
    myDelegate d = delegate(IntPtr handle, string typename, IntPtr lParam)
        { (((GCHandle) lParam).Target as List<string>).Add(typename); return true; };
    WinApi.EnumResourceTypes(module, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(d), (IntPtr) pin);
    pin.Free();
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

---

Declaring the delegate inside a method is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434880/c-sharp-cant-declare-delegate-within-a-method) at this point. Even if compiled it causes unmanaged code to crash my application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use an *anonymous method* or a *lambda expression*.

```
// untested
Func<IntPtr, string, IntPtr, bool> inline = (module, typename, lParam) =>
{
    (((GCHandle)lParam).Target as List<string>).Add(typename);
    return true;
};

WinApi.EnumResourceTypes(module, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(inline), (IntPtr)pin);
```

Comment: I would avoid the type specification along with parameters. LHS would do it, isnt it?

Comment: Looks promising. But doesn't work. First `Action` must be `Func`. Then compilation ok, but crashes at the call. Not sure but keyword `delegate` is needed ?

Comment: Well, like I said: untested. You voided the warranty by running it.

Comment: @mini-me does it not crash when going by your original approach?

Comment: @mini-me no, `delegate` keyword is not required here and is not going to make a difference.

Comment: Hmm, you could replace `Func<>` with `myDelegate` but I don't think that matters.

Comment: @nawfal see original post + edit. Both versions work fine. Trying to declare the delegate inside of my method seems to cause crashes.

Comment: @mini-me that's pretty odd. How about `public static string[] getResourceTypes(IntPtr module)
        {
            Func<IntPtr, string, IntPtr, bool> inline = EnumResTypeProc;

            Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(inline);
        }` without declaring `delegate` outside the method? Not complete code, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @nawfal I'll try it. Maybe important: App crashes in unmanaged code. So I don't get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this links:

[microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315582)

[How to write callbacks in C# and .NET](http://www.myelin.co.nz/notes/callbacks/cs-delegates.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or my example:

```
public delegate void AsyncMethodCaller(strind inputdata);


 void someMethod()
{
//
// ... some actions 
//
AsyncMethodCaller caller = new AsyncMethodCaller(this.ProcessInputData);

   // Initiate the asychronous call.
   IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke("my data");
}

void ProcessInputData(string inputData)
{
    // some actions
}
```